# Validate field against a value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

What kind of validation I am looking for, if I want that:

My field :provider has to have the value of 'facebook'.

I know I can do a regex and use `validates :provider, :format => /regex/` But I found weird have to use a regex for a fixed value as 'facebook'.

Any other way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What's the point of storing constant value in db?

Comment: scalability, I guess. Latter on, more providers may be needed, like twitter, etc.

Comment: Right now I just want provider to be Facebook. Later on, I might add Twitter.

Answer (score 6):

You can use inclusion validation

```
validates :provider, :inclusion => { :in => ['facebook'] }
```